# Generic interface, which can map object properties to another interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to make types for my FormBuilder component, but got some troubles with property type extraction.

here is simplified code:

```
interface NumericField {
    type: 'numeric'
}

interface TextField {
    type: 'text'
}

type Field = NumericField | TextField

type Fields = Record<string, Field>

export type PropertyTypeExtractor<T extends Fields> = {
    [Property in keyof T]
    : T[Property] extends NumericField ? number
    : T[Property] extends TextField ? string 
    : never;
};

const fields = {
    numericField: {
        type: 'numeric'
    },
    textField: {
        type: 'text'
    }
}

const data = {
    numericField: 42,
    textField: 'lorem ipsum'
}

function createForm<T extends Fields>(fields: T, data: PropertyTypeExtractor<T>) { }

// fields: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"text"'.
createForm(fields, data)
```

As i can see, the main problem goes from `type Fields = Record<string, Field>`, typescript doesn't know which exactly type comes to `Field`. Even if `type === 'text'` means this can be the only `TextField`.

Typescript smart enough for this:

```
const anotherFields: Fields = {
    numericField: {
        type: 'numeric'
    },
    textField: {
        type: 'text'
    }
}

const field = anotherFields.numericField // field: Field
if (field.type === 'numeric') {
    console.log(field) // field: NumericField
}
```

so is here some workaround for my case?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIFcC21gIGLAQA2AJsgN4BQyNyYAngA4QBcyA5CFjgu5QL6VKoSLEQoAKhAAeYAsTJVadJqw6RZfQZQbNk80sgC8ablFwGyAH2RTZlobpSWAzseQAlCAgD2UEgA8LmDmIADmADT6hKQAfEIyjH5gKnoAClA+zFAMEqoAorJQiGB+ARLIMpAgJG6use5KtADaGVnQDMigyADWEPQ+MLYAutS0bBKtmdkMw5WyEDVuGNjm+DFkAPzIXJgARtBjNBNT7Tn0c1WLtbZVlsjbwaFhyEfIbCAQAG7QANwC-0ovhAwWQMA2bhMTRoux4ljY0OUqTUnDMuD4yn4ETeGjkGwRb2UTjY7FxGNogm0wNBJDgYDgjTesLW8OQABYAEzYol3fEcIh+CCYLqMFxYLRCGDoEAIMDAHwgZAIKAQOkQPB+TDlebVG71AAU4IULgmUVp9LYbRm9DyzEKIRKZQksQAlBRkNoAPSesEQiaqDhPUBhdhdNwgHwpOAuFzAMIgOB7IgoUrIjgAIlx6fYADogSq1RqoJhDRCzXS4C6hECFaC4BGwAALaCuNiuRnKZkWPmIomqEld3hvLE43kKAlI2jE9RVck0SlCakpI2GEz1yPNqCuHOD+7e33j6IKYRDUsKHNOYxGEyo1bot2I6k+ZM5gVhM+kN37lckNgrOEbAIQA)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that typescript is evaluating and widening your type to type `Fields` when passed as an argument to the function. You can solve this in a few ways:

1. Pass the fields directly to the function inline:

```
createForm({
    numericField: {
        type: 'numeric'
    },
    textField: {
        type: 'text'
    }
}, data)
```

2. Use `as const` to prevent type widening of the fields variable:

```
const fields2 = {
    numericField: {
        type: 'numeric'
    },
    textField: {
        type: 'text'
    }
} as const;

createForm(fields, data)
```

3. Join into one parameters type, so the inference applies to the whole object. I'm not 100% on the fundamentals on why this works - but I believe it's something to do with the inference for the type happening at the same time, rather than trying to find a best fit when comparing two separate types:

```js
type FormParameters<T extends Fields> = { fields: T, data: PropertyTypeExtractor<T> };

function createForm<T extends FormParameters<any>>(parameters: T){ }

createForm({ fields, data })
```